# Button Click Delay inside ScrollView

Tags: android

I have an android activity that takes up more then the full screen so I place it inside a ScrollView. There is a button at the very bottom of my Activity and when I scroll down there is a delay in which I can click the button. The delay is until the scrollbar fades away and then the button can be clicked.

This is not a very long time, but for a user it may seem like it and it is very annoying so is there a way to make the buttons clickable while still scrolling or make that time shorter at least?

Comment: I don't think this is standard behavior. What device are you running on? Can you post a link to an apk that has a scrollview and buttons in it I can test it on a few devices and let you know if it has this behavior.

Comment: Yeah I have the APK I am working on in my e-mail, let me upload it somewhere for you to download. Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?odh4eyap2i928y8

Comment: Oh and use the tab that says mixtape to test.. the download button is functional and will download a cd to your phone.. lol

Comment: Same behavior for me. Strange. What does the code look like? Are you using an onScrollListener?

Comment: I am not at home so I can't show you the exact code, but it is using a viewflipper with a scrollview and buttons inside the scrollview. No onScrollListener, just onClickListeners for the buttons based on their ID

Comment: Was it solved? I am facing the same situation here